# Displaying List<Datetime> to a Listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
DateTime StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);
DateTime EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text);


List<DateTime> datetimerange = new List<DateTime>();
while (DateTime.Compare(StartDate, EndDate) <= 0)
{
    datetimerange.Add(StartDate);
    StartDate = StartDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

how can i display the list of dates and display it to listbox?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What don't you like with code you pasted? Btw, you can use comparison operators on DateTime (>, <, ==).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose, I have a listbox with ID lb; just set it's DataSource property equal to your datetime list and call the list.DataBind method.

```
 List<DateTime> datetimerange  = new List<DateTime>();
 lb.DataSource = datetimerange ;
 lb.DataBind();
```

Comment: @CarloAdap you are welcome, I will be glad if you mark my answer as accepted answer, there is tick mark below the vote button.

Answer (score 0):

```
Lstbox.DataSource=datetimerange
```

Where Lstbox is ListBox object

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var datetime in datetimerange)
{
     listBox1.Items.Add(datetime.ToString());
}
```